# Replacing unknown substring?

Tags: string

```
public static String updatedStr(){

  String [] ar= {"green","red","purple","black"};
  String str="The colors are (blue), (blue), and (yellow). I prefer (orange)";
```

I would like a final output string of "The colors are green, red, and purple. I prefer black."

Comment: This sounds not easy. You have to build a list of "arguments": find start and end of each argument such as (blue). and store (argPos, fromPos, toPos) : In step 2 build the whole string new, step by step, and replace the arguments with the replacements

Comment: Are you keeping the parentheses in the final string?

Comment: no, I do not want parentheses in the final string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it without using `replace`. Just iterate over the input `String` and add to a `StringBuilder` parts of the original `String` (that are not contained in parentheses) and the replacement words instead of the parts contained in parentheses.

```
public static String updatedStr()
{
    String [] ar= {"green","red","purple","black"};
    String str="The colors are (blue), (blue), and (yellow). I prefer (orange)";

    StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder ();
    int x = 0;
    int pos = 0;
    for(int i = str.indexOf('(', 0); i != -1; i = str.indexOf('(', i + 1)) {
        out.append (str.substring(pos,i)); // add the part between the last ) and the next (
        out.append (ar[x++]); // add replacement word
        pos = str.indexOf(')', i) + 1;
    }
    out.append (str.substring(pos)); // add the part after the final )
    return out.toString ();
}
```

This method returns :

```
The colors are green, red, and purple. I prefer black
```

This code makes some simplifying assumptions. For example, the number of elements in the replacements array should be at least as high as the number of words to be replaced. A more complete implementation should contain additional checks.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm currently trying to get "The colors are green, red, and (yellow). I prefer (orange)"  when ar={"green","red"}. Any tips would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by calculating the position of where you are replacing and saving them in an array as follows:

```
public static String updatedStr(){

      String [] ar= {"green","red","purple","black"};
      String str="The colors are (blue), (blue), and (yellow). I prefer (orange)";
      ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
      int pos [] = new int[ar.length]; // save locations here

      for(int i = str.indexOf('(', 0); i != -1; i = str.indexOf('(', i + 1)) {
          arr.add(str.substring(i + 1, str.indexOf(')', i)));
          pos[arr.size()-1] = i; // save it!
      }

      // replace from right to left
      for (int j=pos.length-1;j>=0;j--){
          String newStr = str.substring(0, pos[j]+1) + ar[j] + str.substring(str.indexOf(')',pos[j]+1), str.length());
          str = newStr;
      }

     return str;
}
```

The trick here is that I'm replacing from right to left so that the positions of where I need to replace do not move when I am replacing them.

Comment: Thank you! I tried to implement this for an instance where ar={"green","red"}. In this case, replacing from right to left would give me an incorrect output. I would like the output to be "The colors are green, red, and (yellow). I prefer (orange)" so that the replacements are given for the appropriate positions, and the rest of the string is unchanged. Do you have any tips on how to achieve this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, you example is inconsistent in it's use of parenthesis.  Do you have more slots to replace than values in ar?